# How to verify an alert is not present using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have tests that involve required fields and alert boxes. When you don't fill out the required field, an alert box should display. I am checking for this alert box by using

```
ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()
```

When I fill out the required field, I want to verify that an alert no longer appears. How can I do this using Selenium and Java?

Comment: Just for clarification, does a physical javascript alert pop up, or an alert box as in just a red box that appears on the page

Comment: @sircapsalot It is a physical javascript alert pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of webdriver

```
public boolean isAlertPresent(){
    try{
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    }catch (NoAlertPresentException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver,10).untill(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent);
        return true;
    } catch (TimeOutException e) [
        return false;
    }
}
```